# use scrollTop in Aside not the html,body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

i try to use scrollTop ,
when user Click on the ( *li* ) element i get the (*data-id*) from (*li*) and scroll to the box in aside that have the same id;

problem is when i click the for example (*li*) number 2 every things fine but when i click it again aside scroll back to top and if you click rapidly it get worst

```js
var aside = $('.aside');

$("li").on('click',function (){

 id = $(this).data("id")

 $('.aside').animate({
            scrollTop: $('div.item[data-id="' + id + '"]').offset().top
        }, 300, 'linear')

});
```

```css
 
 html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
 }

.aside {
 height: 100%;
 width: 400px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right:0;
 background: #ccc;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

.estateWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.item {
 float: right;
 margin: 0px;
 padding:0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 margin-bottom: 100px
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> index </title>
 <script src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <ul>
  <li data-id="1">1</li>
  <li data-id="2">2</li>
  <li data-id="3">3</li>
  <li data-id="4">4</li>
 </ul>


<div class="aside">
 <div class="estateWrap">
  <div class="item" data-id="1">1</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="2">2</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="3">3</div>
  <div class="item" data-id="4">4</div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider  that the offset top position of your `item` elements change after they have been scrolled. The top value becomes `0`. That is why after you click on the same link again it will go all the way up to `0`.

You could add the current top position of the parent aside element like so:

```js
var aside = $('.aside');

function scrollAside (topPos) {
    aside.animate({
        scrollTop: topPos
    }, 300, 'linear')
}

$("li").on('click',function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id"),
        crntScrollPos = aside.scrollTop(),
        top = $('div.item[data-id="' + id + '"]').offset().top;
    if (top + crntScrollPos !== crntScrollPos) {
        scrollAside(top + crntScrollPos);
    }
});
```

```css
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.aside {
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.estateWrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.item {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-id="1">1</li>
    <li data-id="2">2</li>
    <li data-id="3">3</li>
    <li data-id="4">4</li>
</ul>


<div class="aside">
    <div class="estateWrap">
        <div class="item" data-id="1">1</div>
        <div class="item" data-id="2">2</div>
        <div class="item" data-id="3">3</div>
        <div class="item" data-id="4">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position instead of offset:

```
position();
```

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.